# how to find the remainder of division

Tags: math, binary

Q=A/B , Q is a real number expressed as a pair of 8 bits:

- most significant 8 bits for the integer part
- least significant 8 bits for the fractional part
- the number is unsigned

for example:

0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 .  0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0

Can you find the remainder of division if you know B, on a paper? how?

I'll give an example:

2/172 :

0000 0010 . 0000 0000 /

1010 1100 . 0000 0000

=0000 0000 . 0001 0010

0000 0000 . 0001 0010 *

1010 1100 . 0000 0000

=0000 0000 . 1100 0001 (should be 2, or at least something greater than 1.5)

Comment: How is this question related to programming? Just because it involves binary?

Comment: I'm trying to do something in Verilog, and I cannot use ceil or floor functions... they are not synthesizable

Comment: To find the remainder, in addition to B you must know A or Q. Which do you know?

Comment: I know all of them A,B and Q

Comment: So doesn't `A-B*floor(Q)` give you the answer? Given your representation, `floor(Q) = Q & 0xFF00` (i.e. clear the 8 LSBs).

Answer (score 1):

There are two algorithms: restoring and non-restoring. This is very well described in [Division Algorithms and Hardware Implementations by Sherif Galal and Dung Pham](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~ingrid/ee213a/lectures/division_presentV2.pdf). And [here](http://www.ijareeie.com/upload/2013/july/59_VHDL.pdf) is about implementation in VHDL.